# PHP dynamical variable declaration

Tags: php, variable-declaration

I'm dynamically declaring variables using the following code:

```
$fields = array('name1', 'name2');

foreach($fields as $field) {
    $$field = false;
}
```

The problem is there are variable names that overlap, since I'm using more than one array.

The question is: How could I append a letter to the variable name using the previous method?

For example if we were to append the letter **F** to the previous example, then we'd get **$Fname1, $Fname2**.

I tried to do **$F$field** but that doen't work, I also tried to set **$field = "F"+$field** inside the loop but didn't work either.

Comment: If you're running ino problems with this, then perhaps PHP telling you that it isn't the best way to o whatever it is you're trying to do.... perhaps explain what you're trying to achieve, and we may be able to show you a better alternative approach.... perhaps even something as simple as `$fieldSet = array_fill_keys($fields, false);`.... but if you have duplicate variable names, then you're certainly approaching this the wrong way

Comment: I agree with Mark - IMO there aren't many situations where you *need* to use variable variables. Often just using an associative array will do the trick but let you circumvent problems like this from happening.

Comment: The array is used to set variable names, build form fields, and sql queries dynamically. The only problem so far is in case of overlapping field names (when using more than one table)

Comment: To concatenate strings you use a period ".", not a plus symbol "+".

Comment: @C.Liddell I can't believe I overlooked that... Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$fields = array('name1', 'name2');

foreach($fields as $field) {
    $field = "F" . $field;
    $$field = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
$fields = array('name1', 'name2', 'name1', 'name2', 'name2');

foreach($fields as $field) {
    while(!is_null($$field)) {
        $field = "F".$field;
    }
    $$field = false;
    var_dump($field);
}
```

Output:

```
string(5) "name1"
string(5) "name2"
string(6) "Fname1"
string(6) "Fname2"
string(7) "FFname2"
```

So you will append `F` letter for each overlapped variables:)